# Copy entire database contents (schema and data)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to copy the contents (tables, views, procs, DATA, etc.) of a SQL Server database and copy it to another SQL Server database.  I need to do this entirely in a script as I am not able to carry over files to the destination web server.  Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, how can I accomplish this?

*Note:  The database I am copying to will have the same name and be completely empty.*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can script the database schema and data using SSMS

Right click on the database.  Choose tasks....then choose generate sql scripts.

Specify all objects.  Then in the options menu choose at the bottom to generate scripts for data.

Below are some links that will be helpful

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/16/sql-server-2005-generate-script-with-data-from-database-database-publishing-wizard/

Comment: Though I modded this up, please do read your scripts. In a complex environment you may have out of order functions, etc.

Comment: @iivel ...Note in SQL Server Managment Studio the option to "Generate Scripts for dependent objects" actually does a good job of keeping dependent objects in order.

Comment: I certainly believe you and is why I think you have the answer right on. Perhaps it's an artifact of the enviornments I've worked in that require separate scripts for each object, but the ordering can be 'wonky' in how it likes to put things together. I think it is always worth a review before running.

Answer (score 3):

You can backup the database and restore to any instance you'd like. Since I don't like posting the "how to" when I learned it someplace else originally - here's the MSDN describing the process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx

It is how we do things in our production environment. We back up and restore to our other instances.

Comment: I need to do this entirely in a script as I am not able to carry over files to the destination web server.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I completely missed that part of your question. I think John Hartsock's answer should take care of your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to restore from a backup, but since you can't copy files to the file system, the Copy database wizard will do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx